# How to manipulate `string` to given format using PHP

Tags: php

I have 20 digits|length string, example: `22223333333334444333`. How to manipulate with given format, like this: `00-00-000-000-000-0000-000` in PHP?

expected result: `22-22-333-333-333-4444-333`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some Regular Expressions to get it done in a few steps.

```
<?php

// Test string
$string = "22223333333334444333";

// Pattern: 22-22-333-333-333-4444-333
$pattern = "/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{3})/";

// Get all the matching elements in the pattern
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

// Remove the first element from the results (it's the entire string, we don't want that)
array_shift($matches);

// Join all the others matches with "-"
$formatted = implode('-', $matches);

// And there you have your formatted string
var_dump($string, $formatted);

// Output
// '22223333333334444333' (length=20)
// '22-22-333-333-333-4444-333' (length=26)
```

Comment: The best answer so far 